# Is there any way to get a details pane in Ubuntu 14.04 like in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, nemo

Is there any way to get the **details pane**, preferably in Nemo? I am particularly interested in the duration, bit rate of music files and videos.
I realize I can view the information in List View but I was wondering if there is an option for Icon View.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus and Thunar has both got this capability in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this what you are looking for or something else?

Comment: No, I found that. What I need is this in the file manager itself (instead of going into properties) as shown in Windows here:
http://i.imgur.com/rgUnIYC.jpg

Comment: He's looking for a `pane` that shows the information.